# API response - gathering errors from included classes

Tags: php, rest, error-handling

I'm working on a RESTful and am stuck on message gathering for returning to the user. Basically, depending on the options selected, a few classes will be included dynamically. I'll try to provide a real-world break down. We have a HTML-email-tempalte maker - depending on the template chosen a php script will be included. This script may have warnings and I need to pass them "upstream" so that the API can report them. So we have something like this ( -> = includes )

API -> HTMLGenerator -> (dynamically) template-script.php

I need the template-script to be able to report errors to the API controller so the API can report them to the API user. Not sure the best way/practice to accomplish this.

So far , my thoughts are maybe a singleton or session variable that the template-script can add messages to, then the API Controller can report them. Any thoughts?

Main API

REST create by POST to /v1/html basically just:

```
class API {
   require($dynamic_script);
   $errors = array('warnings'=>array('warning1',waring2'));
   //set http header and return JSON
}
```

HTMLGenerator

```
class HTMLGenerator {
//basically some wrappers for junior / non-programmers 
  function addHeading($text) {
    //Add a header and do some checks. 
    if(strlen($text) > $warnTooLong )
       HTMLErrors::addWarning("Message");

  }
}
```

Dynamic Script

```
$h = new HTMLGenerator();
$h->addHeader($text);
$h->addImage($imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom error handler.

See this link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

It allows us to handle a error that might be thrown to capture it and process it. So, when you capture it, you can pass this to the parent class and furthur upstream for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Global object would work, set_error_handler too, but these are just hacks. The cleanest option is to modify your app elements to do what they are suppose to do - return those messages.

These shouldn't be too hard to do:

```
function myOldFunction($param1, $param2)
{
  // do something
}
```

modify this way:

```
function myOldFunction($param1, $param2, array &$messages = array())
{
  // do something
  $messages[] = 'hey mama, i\'m on stack overflow!';
}
```

usage:

```
$messages = array();
myOldFunction(1, 2, $messages);
print_r($messages);
```

Comment: Let me add one more note, which may suggest a global hack is the best. The scripts that are included are meant to be created by very junior programmers. So its calling functions in our main HTMLGenerator class. So a script looks something like this: `code` $h = new HTMLGenerator(); $h->addHeader($var); - so the scripts trapping and collecting errors won't really work. Its the HTMLGenerator class neeeding to pass back to the main API Controller - bypassing the intermediary script of sorts - make sense? Any elegant way to this. We are trying to have all methods not return anything for the junior

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand organization of your scripts, could you provide an example of both sides (HTMLGenerator & template-script.php)? Please mark which code belongs to which script.

Comment: Edited the original post. Very oversimplified due to proprietary nature of some of the code - but hopefully that will show the basic workflow. The dynamic script will just be instructions. Exceptions will be handled correctly, but most of these are warnings or errors to report back so the API user can decided what to do. Just because the text is too long, for example, doesn't mean it doesn't work, it just might not look the best or wrap. These are the warnings/errors we are trying to collect to report. Thanks in advacne

Comment: You could store warnings/errors inside your HTMLGenerator class, as private $errors (array) property. That way HTMLGenerator instance could add it's own errors and you could also implement public method addError() so dynamic script could add error too.